# rails nested attributes rails record_not_found when update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I have 2 models like:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :passengers
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers, allow_destroy: true
end

class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :customer
end
```

`customer_params` contain :

```
:name,...
:passengers_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy]
```

and when pass `passengers_attributes` to update `customer` (id=1) like

```
{
  "passengers_attributes": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "id": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

With passenger `"abc"` is new record

When i run `customer.update_attributes!(customer_params)`, it raise error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Passenger with ID=5 for Customer with ID=1`

Do you know this error? i need your help. Thanks

Comment: What is `customer`? That error means that you are doing `Customer.find(5)` and that record can't be found.  How do you manage to fetch the `customer` object will answer your question, as it seems you are trying to find an non existing record.

Comment: I think the error is that the Passenger with ID 5, could not be found. (i.e. customer.passengers.find(5) would raise a RecordNotFound error. Can you show us the form view?

Comment: when i change passengers info for customer with new passeger record like i mention above, we have no passenger with id = `5`, it raised error. So if i want to create new passenger for this customer, i have to pass passenger param without id, ex:
{
  "passengers_attributes": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
    }
  ]
}

Thanks everyone

Comment: @TaiTriVo Did you figure it out? I am struggling with same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

**Found your error here**

```
{
  "passengers_attributes": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "id": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

You can't send id in parameters here. Id can't be modified or you can insert it manually.

Here your customer don't have passenger with id "5".that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: passengers_attributes are nested_attributes, so id is required to update.

Comment: Do you have record with id 5 ?